# How to disable automatic login on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, login, password, lts

Sorry for my bad English.

At home I have a shared Ubuntu computer. However, every time it boots, the system automatically logs in to my account without a password (eventhough my account has a password set through the system settings)

Comment: Hmm... ref back to 2012, ten year old answers. Well, I added a more recent answer there.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simple. In your Ubuntu system, go to settings -> Users. In this window, uncheck the "*Automatic Login*" option listed under your user.
Note: You can only disable this option once you unlock it using the option at the top of the window.

[image: Users window]